# iOS 11 deletes all cookies when closing browser

Tags: ios, cookies

I am setting a cookie by the Javascript code below:

```
document.cookie = "cookieAccepted=true";
```

However, when closing (swipe up) iOS 11 browser (Chrome or Safari) the cookies seem to be deleted.

Does anyone know how to keep / store the cookie (even after swiping up to force-close iOS apps)?

Note: also suffixing `;path=/` in the cookie value does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it: `expires` is a mandatory option for iOS to store cookies. So, I implemented:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(+ now + (1440 * 86400000)); // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
document.cookie = "cookieAccepted=true;expires="+now.toGMTString()+";path=/";
```

Thus, the `cookieAccepted` cookie will expire after 4 years (1440 days).